# Universal Link not navigating to the correct website

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to get universal links working in my app. I...

- have my server set up
- is a fully qualified domain...
- has a valid certificate
- has `.well-known` at the root...
- a file called `apple-app-site-association`

I added the Associated Domains Capability to my app. I'm using this as my entry for it:

`applinks:subdomain.mydomain.com?mode=developer`

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains) says the `apple-app-site-association` file should be formatted as follows:

```json
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "ABCDEFGHIJ.com.me.myapp.debug",
                    "ABCDEFGHIJ.com.me.myapp.alpha",
                    "ABCDEFGHIJ.com.me.myapp.beta",
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/poc/*",
                        "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /poc/."
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I threw some URLs in a notes file on the device using the following variants:

```bash
subdomain.mydomain.com/poc/
subdomain.mydomain.com/poc
subdomain.mydomain.com/poc/index.html
```

When I tap those links, a browser opens and the message I get is `Cannot GET <path>`.

I'm thinking I have a server issue, but I'm not sure. If you've got ideas on what I'm ****ing up and how to fix it, I welcome your responses.

Additionally, on my device, I have developer mode enabled and when I validate the domain under Diagnostics, it says "Opens Installed Application" and "The URL is a universal Link for the app with identifier "ABCDEFJHIJ.com.me.myapp.debug""

Comment: I was about to comment to try the developer diagnostics but you have just edited to say that's what you have done. If the developer diagnostics say that the app will be opened, that is what should happen. Have you implemented [the required code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app) to handle the incoming url?

Comment: @Paulw11 The site is rendered with a script and there was a minor path issue that `curl -v` revealed after comparing it with Apple's site. It also works for google, for anyone working with google deep link stuff (`assetlinks.json` or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

`curl -v` to the rescue. A lightbulb went off that Apple probably has a bunch of deep links on their website, so with that in mind, I did the following:

```bash
curl -v 'https://www.apple.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association'
```

I compared the output of that with the output from

```bash
curl -v 'https://mywebsite.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association'
```

It turns out I had a minor server config issue.